# How can i make it so that instead of repainting this object it just paints it multiple times at multiple points?

Tags: c#

Hey so i am trying to make it so that when i "shoot" it leaves a gunshot in each spot. Well it just keeps repainting it instead of leaving multiple. I know why it does this (because its in the paint event and it repaints each times the timer makes it refresh) but i don't know how to actually fix it.

Heres the class itself

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Media;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Paintball
{
    class PaintballClass
    {
    private SoundPlayer mySound;
    private Image myImage;

    public Point shotLocation; 

    public PaintballClass (System.IO.Stream aSound, Image anImage)
    {
        mySound = new SoundPlayer();
        mySound.Stream = aSound;
        mySound.Load();

        myImage = anImage;
    }

    public void playSound()
    {
        mySound.Play();
    }

    public void locateShot(Point location)
    {
        shotLocation = location;
    }

    public void displayShot(Graphics g)
    {
        g.DrawImage(myImage, shotLocation);
    }


    }
}
```

And heres the form its in

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Paintball
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Target targ;
    private PaintballClass shot;
    private static Random rand = new Random();
    private const int SPEED = 5;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int x1 = rand.Next(pictureBox1.Width);
        int y1 = rand.Next(pictureBox1.Height);
        targ = new Target(new Rectangle(x1, y1, 15, 15), pictureBox1.ClientRectangle, Brushes.Black, SPEED);
        shot = new PaintballClass(Paintball.Properties.Resources.Gunshot, Paintball.Properties.Resources.Untitled);
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        shot.displayShot(e.Graphics);
        targ.paint(e.Graphics);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        targ.move();
        Refresh();
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        shot.playSound();
        shot.locateShot(e.Location);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Clearly you need a `List<Point>` to store shots.

Answer (score 1):

store the shots in a list: `public List<Point> shotLocations = new List<Point>();`
Iterate over each of them and display them in your draw method:

```
public void displayShots(Graphics g)
{
    foreach(var shotLocation in shotLocations)
        g.DrawImage(myImage, shotLocation);
}
```

In the `locateShot` method, add the location to `shotLocations`:

```
public void locateShot(Point location)
{
    shotLocations.Add(location);
}
```

And when the shot dies you can clear the list and redraw.